# Youtube Members API return 403

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am having some difficulty in accessing the members.list Youtube API. I've gotten my scope approved for the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator, but for some reason it still return 403 when I access it with the access token.

Here are the list of scopes that got returned from Google API when I refresh my token

"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly openid [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%22),

and as we can see, it returns the required scope for the members API, but I'm still getting 403 error message

```json
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
            "domain": "youtube.common",
            "reason": "forbidden"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've raised an issue with Google in this issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326362541, but if anyone have any idea why is this happening, It would be greatly appreciated if you could help.

Thank you everyone!